# Rails require statements in environment config files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, statsd, datadog

In my `config\environments\development.rb` and `config\environments\production.rb` files, I set some global variables. In the example below, I have a a `Redis` instance that points to our cache, and a `Statsd` instance that points to the DataDog agent.

```
config.x.cache = Redis.new(url: ENV["CACHE"])  
config.x.statsd = Statsd.new('localhost', 8125)
```

In the case of Redis, I added `gem 'redis'` to my gem file, ran `bundle install` and everything worked fine. In the case of StatsD, however, it seems that I need to also add `require 'statsd'` at the top of the `development.rb` and `production.rb` files in order to be able to create the instance. Of course, I also added `gem 'dogstatsd-ruby'` to my gem file and ran `bundle install`, but that didn't seem to be enough. If I don't add the `require` statement at the top of the config files, I get the following error when I try to run my Rails app:

```
uninitialized constant Statsd (NameError)
```

Can anyone explain why I have to add the `require` statement only in this particular case (StatsD), or is there is a better way to do this? Thanks!